# Facebook audience network stuck on waiting for ad request

Tags: android, facebook, audience

I have integrated latest sdk 6.5.0 on my android app but ads not showing status of adunit is requesting ads but on property level its stuck on waiting for ad request . Live ads not working i am getting near to 500 to 2k requests daily but no impression is delivered by facebook how to fix can any one help

Comment: did you find any solution

Comment: If you are using rewarded video ads, make sure your app is listed in "Game" category or else you won't get any impression. If you are using mediation like "Amob" then remove Audience Network From Waterfall and only use bidding setup.

Comment: @liaqatbaba have you got any solution for this?